# Is being redundancy-free a hereditary property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

By a *closure system*, I mean a set $X$ together with a collection of subsets of $X$ deemed "closed", such that arbitrary intersections of closed sets are themselves closed. These are also sometimes called "generalized topological spaces" in the literature.

Now let $X$ denote a closure system. Call a subset $A$ of $X$ *redundancy-free* iff for all $B \subsetneq A$, we have $\mathrm{cl}(B) \subsetneq\mathrm{cl}(A)$. In other words, $A$ is redundancy-free iff it is minimal among all subsets of $X$ whose closure equals $\mathrm{cl}(A)$. For example, $\{(2,0),(3,0)\}$ is a redundacy-free subset of the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z},$ if by "closed subset" we mean "subset that is closed under the group operations."

> **Question.** Let $X$ denote a closure system, and $A$ denote a redundancy-free subset of $X$. Is it true that every subset of $A$ is necessarily redundancy-free?

It seems obvious that the answer is "yes," but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle X,\mathscr{F}\rangle$ be a closure system, and suppose that $C\subsetneqq B\subsetneqq A\subseteq X$. Suppose further that $\operatorname{cl}C=\operatorname{cl}B$. Let $D=B\setminus C$, and let $E=A\setminus D$. Then $E\subsetneqq A$, but if $E\subseteq F\in\mathscr{F}$, then $C\subseteq F$, so $D\subseteq B\subseteq F$, and hence $A\subseteq F$. Thus, $\operatorname{cl}E=\operatorname{cl}A$, and $A$ is not redundancy-free.